# ¿Como pasar una variable por el metodo fopen en c para que lea un archivo?

Tags: c, archivo, fopen

Consigo que mi metodo lea el archivo si le introduzco fopen("nombre.txt","r") pero si le introduczo una variable que el programa lee al usuario no me permite leer el archivo.

Variable: scanf("%s",filename)
No funciona: fopen(filename, "r")

Comment: Bienvenido. No podemos ayudarte si no podemos reproducir el problema.

Comment: Añade el código de un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema. Sin eso va a ser complicado darte una respuesta